# ocelot.json Getting "GlobalConfiguration" values with appsettings.json

Tags: c#, json, docker, docker-compose, ocelot

I set up an Api Gateway using Visual studio 2022. The library I use is "ocelot"

Everything works fine in the development environment, but when I wanted to deploy with docker-compose, it didn't work.

Information about the docker-compose.yml, appsettings.json, ocelot.json file is as follows.

"BaseUrl, "GlobalConfiguration" in the docker-compose.yml file
Hosts:KeycloakServiceInventory,
Hosts:KeycloakServiceInventoryRealmId,
Hosts:InventoryManagementAPI "

I want to change values like in docker-compose. I just couldn't do this.
Can anyone with knowledge on the subject help?

**The content of the ocelot.json file is as follows.**

```
{
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:4000",
    "Hosts": {
      "KeycloakServiceInventory": "http://localhost:8080",
      "KeycloakServiceInventoryRealmId": "inventory_management_realm",
      "InventoryManagementAPI": "https://localhost:4002"
    }
  },

  "Routes": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/inventory/user/token/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/realms/{KeycloakServiceInventoryRealmId}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "{KeycloakServiceInventory}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/gateway/inventory/user/logout",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/realms/{KeycloakServiceInventoryRealmId}/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "{KeycloakServiceInventory}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**The content of the appsettings.json file is as follows.**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production",
  "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://*:4000;http://*:4001",
  "ASPNETCORE_Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Password": "12345",
        "Path": "/app/ssl/wilcard2024.testnet.com.tr.pfx"
      }
    }
  },
  "GatewaySettings": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:4000",
    "Hosts": {
      "KeycloakServiceInventory": "http://localhost:8080",
      "KeycloakServiceInventoryRealmId": "inventory_management_realm",
      "InventoryManagementAPI": "https://localhost:4002"
    }
  },
  "Keycloak": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:8080/realms/inventory_management_realm",
    "ClientId": "InventoryManagementClient",
    "ClientSecret": "FqCf5sQeJTPEJcvvxssoeg5cPGv8",
    "GrantType": "password",
    "Audience": "InventoryManagementClient",
    "Realm": "InventoryManagementClient",
    "GrantTypePermissions": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket"
  }
}
```

**The content of the docker-compose.yml file is as follows.**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apimanagement.gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apimanagementgateway
    container_name: "ApiManagement.Gateway"
    restart: "always"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/ApiManagement.Gateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:443"
      - "4001:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:4000;http://*:4001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=1234
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/ssl/testnet.enerya.com.tr.pfx
      - Keycloak__Authority=http://host.docker.internal,8080/realms/inventory_management_realm
      - Keycloak__ClientId=InventoryManagementClient
      - Keycloak__ClientSecret=FqCf5sQeJTPEJjYzD8XtwZWoeg5cPGv8
      - Keycloak__GrantType=password
      - Keycloak__Audience=InventoryManagementClient
      - Keycloak__Realm=InventoryManagementClient
      - Keycloak__GrantTypePermissions=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket
    volumes:
      - ./src/ApiManagement.Gateway/ssl:/app/ssl
```

**The content of the program.cs file is as follows.**

```
    using ApiManagement.Gateway;
    using Gateway;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
    using Ocelot.Middleware;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;

    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


    #region Docker - Kestrel
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
    {
        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80); // HTTP için
        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ASPNETCORE_Kestrel:Certificates:Default:Path").Value,
                builder.Configuration.GetSection("ASPNETCORE_Kestrel:Certificates:Default:Password").Value);
        });
    });
    #endregion


    #region Ocelot.json
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    builder.Services.AddOcelot();
    builder.Services.ConfigureDownstreamHostAndPortsPlaceholders(configuration);
    #endregion




    var app = builder.Build();
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseCors(allowedResources);
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseFormContentMiddleware();
    await app.UseOcelot();



    app.Run();
```